# How to express elements of list as alternatives?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to do something very simple, convert a list:

```
list = {"Alice","Bob"}
```

into alternatives:

```
alt = "Alice"|"Bob"
```

Of course this can be done manually very easy, but he point is to do it automatically. I want to do this, to use the list data as input for DeleteCases on another list:

```
DeleteCases[list2,"Alice"|"Bob"]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can do `Alternatives@@ list`.

Comment: The symbol `@@` is the shortcut for `Apply`, which replaces the head of an expression. Here, the head `List` of `list` is replaced by `Alternatives`.